# How do I add the nightly Risc Os build as an option to the NOOBs / PINN OS list?

Tags: pi-3, noobs, riscos, pi-zero-w

The latest NOOBs image contains the RISCOS boot binary, but the option to install it dosen't appear on a Pi-3. I guess as the official release only supports Pi-1 + Pi-2, while the nightly build supports the pi-3 and pi-zero. So what magic json tweaks are required to add the beta/nightly OS builds to the NOOBs os option list?